# getting string list from a web service in android app

Tags: android, asp.net, android-listview

I have a web service made in asp.net which returns a list of String . 
here is the code :

```
<WebMethod()> Public Function HelloWorld() As List(Of String)
Dim a As New List(Of String)

    a.Add("2")
    a.Add("2")
    a.Add("2")
    a.Add("2")
    a.Add("2")

Return a
End Function
```

and this is the coding in android app :

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(wsdl_target_namespace,operation_name);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope= new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(soap_address);
Log.d("test", "test");
try{
    httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    Object response = envelope.getResponse();
    txt.setText(String.valueOf(response));
    Log.d("test", String.valueOf(response));
} catch(Exception exception){
    txt.setText(exception.toString());
    Log.d("error_mine", exception.toString());
}
```

this code returns me this in text box :

```
anyType {
    string=2;
    string=2;
    string=2;
    string=2;
    string=2
}
```

but i want this as a list to populate a list view .

how can i do this ?

Comment: you need to parse this using SoapParser and add in ArrayList<String> so that you can pass this in ArrayAdapter of ListView

Comment: Sir ! i am a beginner can you please give me an example

Comment: please no Sir. can you show your actual output.? else you can follow [this sample](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-development-tutorial)

Comment: anyType{string=2; string=2; string=2; string=2;string=2}
this is the output

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code :

```
// ArrayList to store the data from web service : 
// **You can initialize this string globally**
ArrayList<String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

-----------------------------------------------
Object response = envelope.getResponse();
// need to replace this line with the following
-----------------------------------------------

// Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
if (result != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < result.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
        mArrayList.add(result.getProperty(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: when check for result.getPropertyCount() it always gives me 1 but there are 5 items . why this happens ?

Comment: Sir ! can u please give me your email address , so that i get a straight way with you .

Comment: @Rehamk you can find me here [Smart Developers' Lab chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13436/smart-developers-lab)